# Iframe Swapping

Tags: html, css, wordpress, iframe

I have on my Home page a bunch of dropdowns on the pictures and i have a page called Links with an iframe, im using wordpress and visual composer plugin, all links are in a vc text block

My Question: How can i use the same iframe for all the links on home, so when i click a link it goes to links page and changes iframe in wordpress?

Home: http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/

Links Page: http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the content of an iframe, you can you the following.

Your iframe :

```
<div class="my-iframe">
        <iframe id="my_iframe_id" width="100%" height="1080" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"
           src="http://my.site.com/onething/otherthing">
        </iframe>
    </div>
```

and you can update the url with

```
<script>
        function updateIframeSrc(newSrc) {
            document.getElementById("my_iframe_id").src = newSrc;
        }
</script>
```

So, you just need to call `updateIframeSrc(...)` with your new URL when you click on some element you want.

Hope this can help you ;)

**EDIT : Add some code to answer comments**

A quick and dirty way to send param over url is to add it inside you href. You can do it better if you want ;)

```
<a href="http://www.corebusinesssa.co.za/Test/links?urlsrc=http://my.site.com/onething/otherthing" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

Then, you just need to declare the previous function `updateIframeSrc(...)` and call it when you arrive on the destination page.

To know how to get `urlscr` param from your url, you can refer to the following post : [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: i tried this

js: function setURL(url){
    document.getElementById('iframe2').src = url;
}

html: <a href="/Test/links" target="iframe2" onclick="setURL('http://pro-av.panasonic.net/en/varicam/index.html')>Varicam</a>

but when i click save it changes too
    <a href="/Test/links" target="iframe2">Varicam</a>

visual composer text block seems to remove it :/

Comment: If you write this, a click on your href will move you to the new page "/Test/links". Try to put a simple "#" in your href. Or, i think better, just put a span with an "hover" style. 

In fact, here you do not need to go to another page, you juste want to load new content on an iframe.

Comment: i want the links on home to goto the new links page then update the iframe on that page ye, the links and iframe are on 2 different pages

Comment: oh ok... so, pass your url "pro-av....." as parameter when you go on "/test/links", and so , on init, get the url from get params and update the iframe with the method in the main answer ;)

Comment: i know this is a dumb question, how do i do that? :c i'v never done any code before and never js :c

Comment: Thanks for the help :D